# Sending Email through Intent doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm very new to **Android** and was trying to do an app which sends an e-mail. I've gone through few tutorials online and was trying to do this through **Intent** but it doesn't seem to work on the **Emulator**.

Here's what i've done:

OnClick:

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sendemail();
            recipent.setText("");
            subject.setText("");
            message.setText("");

        }
```

Method sendemail():

```
private void sendemail() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] recipients = {recipent.getText().toString()};

            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message.getText().toString());

             try {

                         // the user can choose the email client

                          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose an email client from..."));



                       } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No email client installed.",

                                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                       }

        }
    });
```

It'd be great if you could help me out. 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'?

Comment: No errors but E-mail doesn't get sent.

Comment: I have almost the exact same code as yours without Uri.parse in it so I would guess and say start there. Make sure the information being sent via the email is making it to the intent from where you did setText(). Set up a few Logs to check.

Comment: okay does it work on the emulator too or just the phone? cause I've seen people telling that this wouldn't work on the emulator. Is that true?

Comment: In Emulator have you created your google Account??

Comment: Google Account on the Emulator? I'm not sure what this is dude

Answer (score 0):

Use below code...

```
private void sendemail(){
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"mail-id"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose an email client from..."));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following simple code and I am able to send mail. Try it.

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {""});
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, new String[] {""});
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, new String[] {""});

in.setType("text/plain");
//Intent.createChooser(
startActivity(in);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to send an email using the emulator.

You will need an android device for this and an email account configured on the device so that you can send an email.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@emailaddress.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```